# Converting rows to columns without any calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

I have a table with only a single column. How can I convert these rows to columns?

| ColourCode |
| --- |
| #FFCC00 |
| #339966 |
| #800080 |
| #FF9900 |

The maximum possible number of rows will be 10.

I am expecting this:-

| C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| #FFCC00 | #339966 | #800080 | #FF9900 |

Comment: You've already tagged pivot, so you appear to know how. Why don't you have a go and see how you get on?

Comment: yes, I can see it's possible using the pivot function. But most of the queries using pivots based on the calculated values. is there any workaround in the simplest way?

Comment: Have a go, see how far you get, then post your attempt and someone will help with the final tweaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to dynamic generated column name, if you can combie sql script, you can use combined string to script to execute .

```
with code as (
select '#FFCC00' as ColourCode 
union
select '#339966' as ColourCode 
union
select '#800080' as ColourCode 
union
select '#FF9900' as ColourCode )
select *
from
(select ColourCode , 
'C' + cast( ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by (select 1)) as nvarchar(max)) as rn -- generate sequence number
from code ) as sourcetable
PIVOT  
(  
  max(ColourCode)  
  FOR rn IN ([C1],[C2],[C3],[C4])  -- predifned column Name, if you want to dynamic generated, you should use variable 
) AS PivotTable;
```